# Is there a way to tell the shell (zsh preferably) about a command?

Tags: zsh, alias, tab-completion

I defined an alias:

```
alias school="cd ~/School/3BaFys/"
```

to quickly go to the folder `3BaFys` which contains all of the directories I need this year.

Is there a way to tell `zsh` that when I do:

```
$school Num<TAB>
```

this expands to

```
$school Numerieke\ Methoden
```

where `Numerieke \Methoden` is a sub directory of `~/School/3BaFys/`

eg, tell the shell what `school` actually does and enabling it the be smart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

I just found [this article](http://blog.caioromao.com/2010/12/26/Custom-directory-completion-for-zsh.html) describing how to do it.

Basically you rewrite your alias to a function, and then use some compctl magic on it.

This should solve your problem:

```
school() { cd ~/School/3BaFys/$@; }
compctl -/ -W ~/School/3BaFys school
```

Comment: Actually, this seems so nice I'll probably put something similar in my zsh config as well...

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](https://superuser.com/questions/353161/is-there-a-way-to-tell-the-shell-zsh-preferably-about-a-command/353168#353168), but it might be more convenient to tackle the problem slightly differently.

```
setopt autocd
school=~/School/3BaFys/
```

Type the command line `$school` to change to that directory. Type `$school/Numerieke\ Methoden` to change to *that* directory, and you'll have completion on the `Numerieke Methoden` part (and on `school`, too) out of the box. And you can write things like `xpdf $school/foo.pdf` to access files in that directory without changing to it.

If you don't like polluting your parameter space, you can use a [named directory](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories):

```
hash -d school=~/School/3BaFys/
~school
ls ~school
```